# malloc usage for pointer to structure

Tags: c

This is a part of a program that takes a file which has some shell command.
ex) a || b, a|b, ... and prints out the result in a tree structure.
make_command_stream function takes a shell script as an input and create a structure that contains tree structure of commands.

#### 0. Type definition of command_t and command_stream_t

```
typedef struct command *command_t;
typedef struct command_stream *command_stream_t;
```

#### 1. Definition of a structure: struct command_stream

```
struct command_stream{
    struct command* nodeArray[255];
    int count; 
    int front, rear;
    int max;
};
```

#### 2. Definition of a structure: struct command

```
struct command
{
  enum command_type type;

  // Exit status, or -1 if not known (e.g., because it has not exited yet).
  int status;

  // I/O redirections, or null if none.
  char *input;
  char *output;

  union
  {
    // for AND_COMMAND, SEQUENCE_COMMAND, OR_COMMAND, PIPE_COMMAND:
    struct command *command[2];

    // for SIMPLE_COMMAND:
    char **word;

    // for SUBSHELL_COMMAND:
    struct command *subshell_command;
  } u;
};
```

#### 3. Definition of a function: postfixToTree

```
struct command** postfixToTree(char* postfix, struct command **root){
    struct nStack X;
    struct command *newNode[255] = { 0 };
    struct command *op1,*op2;
    char *p;
    p = &postfix[0];
```

// These are a memory allocation for variables. I know it looks very messy and unreasonable, I couldn't the other way to allocate the memory properly

```
    struct command stackCmd[255] = { 0 };
    char stackBuf[255][255] = { 0 };
    char* pStackBuf[255] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<256;i++){
        pStackBuf[i] = &stackBuf[i][0];
        stackCmd[i].u.word = &pStackBuf[i];
        X.data[i] = &stackCmd[i];
    }
   
    struct command nodeCmd[255] = { 0 };
    char nodeBuf[255][255] = { 0 };
    char* pNodeBuf[255] = { 0 };
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<256;j++){
        pNodeBuf[j] = &nodeBuf[j][0];
        nodeCmd[j].u.word = &pNodeBuf[j];
        newNode[j] = &nodeCmd[j];
    }


    emptyNodeStack(&X);
    int k = 0;
    while(*p){
        char keys[] = ";|&<>";
        
        if(isalpha(*p) || (*p ==':') || (*p == '<') || (*p == '>') || (*p == '-') || (*p == '!')){
            int i = strcspn(p, keys);
            memcpy(pNodeBuf[k],p,i);
            nodeBuf[k][i]='\0';
            pNodeBuf[k+1] = NULL;
            p = p+i;
            newNode[k]->type=SIMPLE_COMMAND;
            newNode[k]->status=-1;
            pushNode(&X,newNode[k]);
            k++;
        }
        
        
        if (*p == '|')
        {
            op1 = popNode(&X);
            op2 = popNode(&X);
            newNode[k]->type=PIPE_COMMAND;
            newNode[k]->status=-1;
            newNode[k]->u.command[0] = op2;
            newNode[k]->u.command[1] = op1;
            pushNode(&X,newNode[k]);
            k++;
            p++;
        }
    }
    *root = popNode(&X);
    return root;
}
```

#### 4. Definition of a function: make_command_stream

```
command_stream_t
make_command_stream (int (*get_next_byte) (void *),
                     void *get_next_byte_argument)
{
    char c = 0;
    char* infix_string= &c;
    infix_string=(char*)checked_malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    char d = 0;
    char* postfix_string = &d;
    postfix_string = (char*)checked_malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    
    command_stream_t csPtr = (command_stream_t)checked_malloc(sizeof(struct command_stream));
    if(csPtr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    csPtr->max = 100;
    
    if(csPtr->nodeArray == NULL){
        free(csPtr);
        return NULL;
    }
    csPtr->front = 0;
    csPtr->rear = 0;
    csPtr->count = 0;
   
    int i = 0;
    c = get_next_byte(get_next_byte_argument);
    while(c!= EOF){
        unsigned int j = 0;
        while(c!=EOF && c!='\n'){
            infix_string[j] = c;
            c = get_next_byte(get_next_byte_argument);
            j++;
            if(j > sizeof(char)*1000){
                infix_string=(char*)realloc(infix_string,sizeof(char)*2000);
            }
        }
        infixToPostfix(infix_string, postfix_string);
        struct command** r;

// After executing this line, the value of csPtr->nodeArray[0] is replace to csPtr->nodeArray
        r = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);

    enqueue(csPtr,r);
            memset(infix_string,0,strlen(infix_string));
        memset(postfix_string,0,strlen(postfix_string));
        i++;
        while(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '){
            c = get_next_byte(get_next_byte_argument);
        }
    }
```

#### 5. First Question.

I want to access the member of the structure.
What I did above is, declare a pointer to a structure, which is called csPtr(command stream pointer).
And I allocated a memory for the structure. After that, I set up the initial values for this structure.
At this moment, am I allowed to access the member of the structure without creating struct object?
Compiler does not complain, but I am not clear what happens if I don't create the structure object.

#### 6. Second question

The purpose of postfixToTree function is to modify the "command stream structure" that I mentioned above.
To be specific, my goal is to get a node of a tree, which is a pointer to structure(struct command*) from the string.My program is currently executing the following line in the make_command_stream function.

```
r = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);
```

I used GDB, broke the line, and examined the value.
However, After I execute the line above, the value of the array[0] got overwrited.
This is what I got from GDB:

Current Line:

```
6: postfix_string = 0x603640 "g++  -c  foo.c "
5: *((**r).u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "true "
3: *(csPtr->nodeArray[1]->u.word) = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x18>
2: *(csPtr->nodeArray[0]->u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "true "
```

Then I execute this line:

```
(gdb) n
```

Expected:

```
6: postfix_string = 0x603640 "g++  -c  foo.c "
5: *((**r).u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "g++  -c  foo.c "
3: *(csPtr->nodeArray[1]->u.word) = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x18>
2: *(csPtr->nodeArray[0]->u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "true "
```

What I got:

```
6: postfix_string = 0x603640 "g++  -c  foo.c "
5: *((**r).u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "g++  -c  foo.c "
3: *(csPtr->nodeArray[1]->u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "g++  -c  foo.c "
2: *(csPtr->nodeArray[0]->u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7e90 "g++  -c  foo.c "
```

Why does my function overwrites the value of the array?

EDITED:

#### 7. Definition of popNode

```
struct command* popNode(struct nStack* s)
{
        struct command *ret=NULL;
        if(!isemptyNode(s))
        {
                ret= s->data[s->top];
                --s->top;
        }
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is **way** too much code for a SO question.  Please reduce this to the [*simplest* code example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates what you're asking about.

Comment: "And I allocated a memory for the structure" - no. You allocated memory for *variable* of your custom type. Structure is just data type, like `int`. There is difference between data type and variable.

Comment: What does `popNode` do?

Comment: I added the definition of pop node.

Comment: Return value is the pointer to a node of tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I allowed to access the member of the structure without creating
>   struct object

You have already allocated space for the struct object. There is not a further step to create a struct object. You can write to this object and read from fields that you have written to previously.

Regarding the second question, it looks like you are overwriting the value here, within `postfixToTree`:

```
*root = popNode(&X);
```

`root` is `&csPtr->nodeArray[0]` in the calling code, and so `*root` is `csPtr->nodeArray[0]`, hence it is overwritten.

Without understanding the whole of the code, I can't say why you've written it this way. But I suspect you are returning a pointer to locally allocated memory. Within `postfixToTree` you define

```
struct command nodeCmd[255] = { 0 };
```

Later you assign a pointer to a member of this array:

```
newNode[j] = &nodeCmd[j];
```

And enter it onto your local data structure `X` (using a `pushNode` function we don't see):

```
pushNode(&X,newNode[k]);
```

`popNode(&X)` presumably retrieves one of these entries from `X`. *But pointers to local data in functions are not valid after the function returns.*

Comment: "But pointers to local data in functions are not valid after the function returns." Could you explain further about this statement?

Comment: I see. Since local variable is erased after the end of the function, the pointer is pointing nowhere after that. Right?

Comment: Accessing the pointer results in undefined behaviour. In practice it will point to whatever value has replaced it in the memory location it points to (probably on the "stack"). But you shouldn't rely on what you think might happen.